# How to get Value less than in a String of Arrays

Tags: c#

```
string[] str = new string[] {"sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri","sat"};
```

Is it possible to use LINQ to get a list of indexes before the input string:
i.e if input string is `thu` ,  my result should be: `sun,mon,tue,wed,thu`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Take()` extension method:

```
str.Take(Array.IndexOf(str, "thu") + 1).ToArray();
// --> returns `["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu"]`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the items **before** the input string you can write:

```
res = str.TakeWhile (s => s != "thu");
```

This will however not include `thu` itself.

But can by fixed by writing:

```
res = str.TakeWhile (s => s != "thu").Concat(new[]{"thu"});
```

But the fastest way of doing it would probably be:

```
var i = Array.IndexOf(str, "thu");
if(i != -1)
{
    var target = new string[i + 1];
    Array.Copy(str, target, i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `IndexOf` with `Where` method on a list instead of an array. Here is the code:

```
string[] str = new string[] { "sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat" };

var strList = str.ToList();

var targetIndex = strList.IndexOf("thu");

var result = strList.Where((s, index) => index <= targetIndex).ToList();
//result = sun, mon, tue, wed, thu
```

Comment: Or you could just do it directly on the array, which avoids unnecessary casting and will be faster especially for larger arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = str.TakeWhile(s => s != "thu").Concat(new string[] { "thu" }).ToArray();
```